# Different results for mean and median function call through apply over missing values

Tags: r, nan, mean, na, median

Noticed that if all values are missing in a matrix, then mean and median give NA and NaN respectively,

for example,

```
x<-as.matrix(c(NA, NA, NA))
apply(x,2, mean, na.rm = TRUE)
> apply(x,2, median, na.rm = TRUE)
[1] NA
> apply(x,2, mean, na.rm = TRUE)
[1] NaN
```

Wondering what could be the reason for this and does it make a difference further downstream if i only check for is.na() for filtering? Since i see that is.na() is TRUE for all while:

```
> is.nan(apply(x,2, median, na.rm = TRUE))
[1] FALSE
```

Comment: This is not really an `apply` issue.  `mean(c(NA, NA, NA), na.rm = TRUE)` would give `NaN` while `median(c(NA, NA, NA), na.rm = TRUE)` would give `NA`

Answer (score 2):

NaN means "Not a Number" and also result from operations like dividing by zero!

Since `mean()` at its heart is calculated in the background somewhat like this `sum(x)/len(x)` (or equivalent) there is a division operation and therefore NaN can be produced if values are missing (since len(NA) is 0). This is not the case for `median()`.

In any case filtering for `is.na()` or `complete` should suffice. Also as per the documentation `is.na()` outputs TRUE for NaN.